# Check if string is already exist and add a number as suffix to the string in the array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a name as "Ryan" and next time entering "Ryan" it should check it has the value,So it should make it "Ryan_1". The same way it should check if anytime someone added again "Ryan" it should change it to "Ryan_2".

Example:

```
nameArray = ["Ryan","John","Ryan_2","Rhonda","Ryan_3","Kylie","Ryan_4","John_2"];
```

I am using below code which is working fine while adding the name first time.

But when I am coming back to the section and editing value Ex: I changed Ryan_2 to "xyz" and again thought of keeping "Ryan" the saved value is becoming "Ryan_4" where as it supposed to be "Ryan_2" in the array. And let say if I am changing "Ryan_4" to "somenewName" now the numbering  of other  duplicate names also get rearranged.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int occurrences = 0;

for(NSString *string in nameArray) {
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        if ([string containsString:value]) {
            [array addObject:string];
        }

        occurrences+= ([string containsString:value] ? 1 : 0);
    }
}       

if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    if (![value isEqualToString:@""]) {
        if (occurrences > 1) {
            value = [value stringByAppendingFormat:@"_%d", occurrences];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what have you thought about changing your `occurrences` based implementation to in order to resolve that?

Comment: do you really need this naming scheme? there are much simpler and faster options which guarantee a unique name...

Comment: @Wain thank you for replying. Actually user will be taking  multiple picture from camera and save them in gallery and from the gallery view they can add name to photo by audio functionality of keyboard so sometimes they add same name to n number pictures.Ex: From West,From West,From West. So that time we need to auto save From west with a numbering.

Comment: what is captionArray?

Comment: Can you guarantee that none of your wicked user will choose himself the 'Ryan_2' username?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an extension like this:

```
extension NSMutableArray {
public func appendWithSuffix(strNewEntry:String) {
    var n = 1
    var new = strNewEntry
    if self.containsObject(strNewEntry) {
        new = strNewEntry + "_\(n)"
        while self.containsObject( new ){
            n += 1
            new = strNewEntry + "_\(n)"
        }
    }
    self.addObject( new )
}}
```

It will look for an exact match and insert if none is found, i.e it will add "Ryan_5" instead of "Ryan", "John_3" instead of "John" and so on.

Another approach may be to iterate thru all entries for comparison or filter the array with `"namexy".hasPrefix("Ryan")` to get max index of name to be inserted.

Comment: @Thank you Michael it is working fine while am updating the name in array. However on delete it is not refreshing the count . I guess i need to add a check on delete and rearrange the order.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)SaveText:(id)sender
{

if (array.count==0)
    {
        [array addObject:_txtAddText.text];
    }else
    {

        for(NSString *string in array)
        {
            if ([string containsString:_txtAddText.text] )
            {
                count = count+1;
              NSString *Localstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",[string stringByAppendingString:@"_"],count];
                 NSLog(@"%@",Localstring);
                [array addObject:Localstring];
                break;
            }else
            {
                [array addObject:_txtAddText.text];
            }
        }

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",array);

}
```